# how to export the data that has been displayed on the page to pdf / excel?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a form like this :

```
<form method="post" action="track_reports.php" name="form">
                    <table id="mytable">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkBadge" onClick="apply(this.checked, 'textBox')"> <font class="category">Badge ID</font>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input id="textBox" class="text sign" type="text" name="badge_id" disabled="disabled">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkEmp" onClick="apply(this.checked, 'textBox2')"> <font class="category">Employee Name</font>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <input id="textBox2" class="text sign" type="text" name="employee_name" disabled="disabled">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input id="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" name="chkEmpOtDate" onClick="apply(this.checked, 'textBox3', 'textBox4')"> <font class="category">OT Date</font>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <font class="category">From</font> <input class="text sign" id="textBox3" type="text" name="alamat" disabled="disabled"> <font class="category">To</font> <input class="text sign" id="textBox4" type="text" name="alamat" disabled="disabled">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
```

This is source for track reports :

```
<div id="bodyText" class="bodyText">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h1>Report Submissions</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php
                    include ("config.php");

                    $bagianWhere = "";

                    if (isset($_POST['chkBadge']))
                    {
                        $badge_id = $_POST['badge_id'];
                        if (empty($bagianWhere))
                        {
                            $bagianWhere .= "badge_id = '$badge_id'";
                        }
                    }

                    if (isset($_POST['chkEmp']))
                    {
                       $employee_name = $_POST['employee_name'];
                       if (empty($bagianWhere))
                        {
                            $bagianWhere .= "employee_name LIKE '$employee_name'";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $bagianWhere .= " AND employee_name LIKE '$employee_name'";
                        }
                    }

                    if (isset($_POST['chkOtdate']))
                    {
                        $ot_date = $_POST['ot_date'];
                        if (empty($bagianWhere))
                        {
                            $bagianWhere .= "ot_date LIKE '%$ot_date%'";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $bagianWhere .= " AND ot_date LIKE '%$ot_date%'";
                        }
                    }

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM t_submissions WHERE ".$bagianWhere;
                    $hasil = mysql_query($query);
                    echo "<table cellspacing='0'>";
                    echo "<tr><th class='th'>Badge ID</th><th class='th'>Employee Name</th><th class='th'>Department</th><th class='th'>OT Date</th></tr>";
                    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
                    {
                       echo "<tr><td class='td'>".$data['badge_id']."</td><td class='td'>".$data['employee_name']."</td><td class='td'>".$data['dept_name']."</td><td class='td'>".$data['ot_date']."</td></tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    ?>
                    <br>
                    <a title="Export to PDF"><img src="images/pdf_files.png"></a>
                    <a title="Export to Excel"><img src="images/excel_file.png"></a>
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;">
            </div>
```

and when i try to search by using badgeid, the data will show.
Now my question how to export the data that has been displayed on the page to PDF/excel ?

Answer (score 1):

For writing in other file formats its not easy to  write code directly, there are libraries which provide easy interface to do such work..

fpdf is the best lib I have used to convert to PDF [demos and download here](http://www.fpdf.org/)

phpexcel is also a very good library that can be used to convert into excel, PDF and many formats..[Download and demo here](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)